# Mysql not returning the exact data from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm saving HTML code in the database. When I get the HTML data from the database to display it as a HTML Page, part of the tags are missing. Any solutions?

HTML Code:

```
<?php echo display_home_page_data(); ?>
```

PHP Code:

```
function update_home_page($data) {
mysql_query("UPDATE `pages`
             SET `page_data` = '" . $data . "'
             WHERE `page_name` = 'Home'");
}

function display_home_page_data() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `page_data`
             FROM `pages`
             WHERE `page_name` = 'Home'");
$result = mysql_result($query, 0);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: store data using `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: How big is `$data`?  What is the data type of `page_data`?  And what is missing?

Comment: What is the output of the function "display_home_page_data"?